# Difference between JavaScript Linkage Object() and reference with =

Tags: javascript

I was going through the videos from Crockford and found out `Object()` linkage topic.

I did not get the exact difference between `Object()` linkage and assignment though.

Can someone put some light to clear this up.

Below is the snippet code and result when executed in Chrome Browser

```
var myObj= {name:"Jack", age:25};

var myLinkObj= Object(myObj);

var myRef=myObj;


myLinkObj.name="John";
myRef.add="India";


alert(myObj.name);  // output John
alert(myObj.add); //output "India"
```

So what is the extra feature that I get form `Object()`. I find it is similar to value reference.

Comment: There is absolutely zero point in using `Object()` here, `myObj === myLinkObj`. What part of which video do you refer to?

Comment: I found in Douglas Crockford: "The JavaScript Programming Language"/2 of 4  video during Linkage explanation. Eventhough example I used is different from what he has shown.

Comment: A link would be nice I meant...

Comment: http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/crockford-tjpl-2.m4v 
Linkage topic starts at around 16:00 min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the extra feature that I get form Object(). I find it is similar to value reference.

That's true. The [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) function does simply return the reference to the given object.

However, that's not what Crockford is talking about in his video. He is trying to explain [prototype inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), and he does not use the `Object` function for that but his [`object` function](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) that he only presents on his website and does not mention this in the talk (maybe another, earlier video?). It is defined as following:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

However, that website is a bit outdated, and the language has evolved. Since EcmaScript 5 we have a native function with this functionality in the language: [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). You'd just do

```
var object = Object.create;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj= {name:"Jack", age:25};

var myLinkObj= Object.create(myObj);

myLinkObj.name="John";
myLinkObj.add="India";


alert(myLinkObj.name); //John
alert(myLinkObj.age); //25
alert(myLinkObj.add);//India
alert(myObj.name);//Jack
```

This works as prototype inheritance concept. myLinkobj inherit the the properties from myObj in this case. 
Thanks,
Brinal